# How to import or use external JS files and functions in my angular web application

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, external-js

I want to integration external code (html, js and css files) into my angular web application.

in this external code, the HTML files is just like this:

index.html

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
</body>

 <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/theme-scripts.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/landing-page/js/imageComparisonSlider.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*Execute a function that will execute an image compare function for each element with the img-comp-overlay class:*/
    initComparisons();
  </script>
<html>
```

as you see, there are several javascript files, and a funciton initComparisons() will be called.

If I only double click index.html, everything works fine. But I copy this html code in one component.html, that was not working. I can not see any animation.

I have googled some solutions, 
and I have change my angular.json file just like this:

```
 "scripts": [
              "src/app/components/landing-page/js/imageComparisonSlider.js",
              "src/app/components/landing-page/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "src/app/components/landing-page/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js",
              "src/app/components/landing-page/js/theme-scripts.js"
            ]
```

and also import all js files in index.html in my angular web application

```
 <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/imageComparisonSlider.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/theme-scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="app/components/landing-page/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
```

and in the component.ts, I also do this:

```
import initComparisons from './js/imageComparisonSlider.js';
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    initComparisons();
  }
```

I added some code in stackblitz; 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qowfwy?file=angular.json

but it was not working.

can somebody help me and give me some suggestion.

Best Regards,

Leo

Comment: If the answers given didn't help, could you maybe create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) which demonstrate the issue?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qowfwy?file=angular.json

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use external js in your angular project you have to import in your angular.json in the  "scripts": [] area that will be allow you to bring the js and make the build after without problem.

Comment: there is no problem after running ng build

Answer (score 0):

After putting the external scripts in angular.json (paths correct and everything), in component you should

```
declare const initComparisons;
// ...
ngOnInit() {
  initComparisons();
}
```

Comment: the pahts are correct, I run ng build and successfull.

Comment: why should use declare const?

Comment: Because without it, TypeScript will object to using undeclared value `initComparisons`, I expect build errors.

Comment: but I have imported this function of external js file

Comment: yout mean; import { initComparisons } from './js/imageComparisonSlider.js';
declare const initComparisons;

Comment: If you _can_ import initComparisons in your component, then by all means do just that. The procedure with modifying angular.json etc. is for the cases where for some reasons you can't (like when the file doesn't have any `export` you could `import`).